# Why is a convex variety called convex?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, convex-geometry, deformation-theory

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety. By Definition 24.4.2 in the 2003 book [Mirror Symmetry](https://www.claymath.org/library/monographs/cmim01c.pdf), $X$ is called convex if $h^1\left( \Sigma, f^*T_X \right) = 0$ for every genus zero stable map $f:\Sigma \to X$.

**Question:** Why is a convex variety called convex?

On page 505 of the book, it was said that $H^1\left( \Sigma, f^*T_X \right) $ measures obstructions to the deformations of the map $f$ (when the structure of the source curve $\Sigma$ is fixed). But I don't know what the obstructions mean, or what zero obstruction means. So I'm also asking the following

**Related question:** What do zero and nonzero obstructions to the deformations of the map $f$ mean?

**My background and what answer I'm looking for:** I have close-to-zero background in deformation theory. So I don't expect to fully understand the precise mathematical meaning over one night. I would appreciate it very much if someone could explain what zero and nonzero obstructions mean in an intuitive way. If this can be further supported by concrete examples for zero and nonzero obstructions, then it will be perfect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there are no obstructions to deformation, i.e. $h^1=0$, then Kodaira's deformation theorem says that the map admits a family of deformations, forming a manifold, near that given map, with tangent space given by $H^0$. You think of genus zero curves as like lines, or line segments, and deforming a line while staying in the variety should be like trying to move around on a set of points in Euclidean space while still being able to move your line segment with you, something you can do when points of the set are connected by line segments, i.e. in a convex set.

For example, if $f$ is the identity map of the projective line, then the space of deformations of $f$ is the space of maps of degree 1, i.e. the space of projective linear transformations of the projective line. The tangent space at the identity element of the group of projective linear transformations is the Lie algebra of vector fields on the projective line, i.e. $H^0$ is the space of linear vector fields, i.e. the space of $2 \times 2$ traceless matrices, so 3 dimensional.

Another example: if $f$ is constant, then the deformations are constant maps, and if the target $X$ is smooth at the image point $x=f(\mathbb{P}^1)$, then $H^0=T_x X$.

Kodaira's book on deformation theory is where I learned about this stuff. Maybe there are better references, especially in the algebraic category.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It is very intuitive and helpful. Also thanks for the reference. Can you say something about $H^1(\Sigma, f^*T_X)$ in the following two cases? Case 1: The map $f$ is a constant, i.e., it maps the source curve to a point. Case 2: The map $f$ is an identity from the line $\mathbb{CP}^1$ to itself.

Comment: So both cases have zero obstructions, right?

Comment: In case one, $f^*T_X$ is trivial, so $H^1 = g(\Sigma) = 0$. In case 2, $f^* T_X = \mathcal O_{\mathbb P^1}(2)$ so $H^1 = 0$ by standard calculations. So yes, both of these are unobstructed.

Comment: @TabesBridges In case one, did you get the result from the Riemann-Roch theorem, i.e., $h^0(\Sigma,L) -h^1(\Sigma,L) = \deg L -g-1$ where the line bundle $L = f^*T_X \cong \Sigma \times \mathbb{C}$? In case 2, excuse my ignorance but what did you mean by standard calculations?

Comment: @YuhangChen First, the last term on the RHS of Riemann-Roch is $+1$, not $-1$. If you plug $h^0(\Sigma, L) = 1$ and $\deg L = 0$ (which uniquely determine that $L$ is trivial), you get $1 - h^1(\Sigma,L) = 0 - g + 1$, which does indeed simplify to $h^1 = g$, but in general $h^1(C,\mathcal O_C)$ is one way of computing the genus of a smooth, projective curve. In case 2 I'm referring to the computation of the cohomology of line bundles on projective space. This particular fact can also be recovered from Serre duality, which identifies $h^1(C,L) = h^0(C, \omega_C\otimes L^\vee)$ which....

Comment: @YuhangChen... in this case is $h^0(\mathbb P^1, \mathcal O_{\mathbb P^1}(-2)\otimes \mathcal O_{\mathbb P^1}(-2)) = h^0(\mathbb P^1, \mathcal O_{\mathbb P^1}(-4)) = 0$, where $\omega_C$ is the canonical bundle (here the same as the holomorphic cotangent bundle), and we use that negative degree line bundles have no sections.

Comment: @YuhangChen Sorry, I suppose a constant map to a variety $X$ will actually have $f^* T_X$ trivial of rank $\dim X$ (too late to edit previous comment). So instead the RR calculation reads $\dim X - h^1(\Sigma,f^* T_X) = (\dim X)(1-g)$, which reduces again to $h^1(\Sigma, f^* T_X) = 0$.

Comment: @TabesBridges Thanks for the detailed explanations. The application of Serre duality to compute $h^1$ is pretty neat!

Comment: @YuhangChen this is a trick you should get familiar with. The only way I can remember the full calculation of cohomology for line bundles on $\mathbb P^n$ is via the slogan "line bundles of non-negative degree have global sections. the only other cohomology is $H^n$ forced by those global sections and Serre duality."